# how to populate a select element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, combobox

I have a select element(combo box) in a jsp page and I want to add elements to this combo box when some event occurs say,click of a button. The elements that I want to add to this combo is sent by the servlet in two string-one for display part,which goes inside ,and the other for value of the element in combo box. In JSP, I split these strings and I am able to extract the items sent by the servlet. Also I am able to add the elements to this combo but,I am unable to add the value part of each element in the combo. Any help?

```
 $.ajax({
         type:"get",
         data:{item:selecteditem},
         url:"Servlet",
         dataType:"json",
         success:function(data){
             var modlist=data.modulelist;
             var tokenlist=data.tokenlist;
             var num=data.num;
             var modarr=new Array();
             var tokarr=new Array();
             var count=1;
             modarr=modlist.split("~delimiter~");
             tokarr=tokenlist.split("~delimiter~");
             while(count<=num){
                 $("#listbox").append("<option value=tokarr[count]>"+modarr[count]+"</option>");
                 count=count+1;
             }

         }

     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var $options = $("#listbox"); // get select element

$options.empty(); // remove existing select options, if you want

//loop through modarr
$.each(modarr, function(index, value) {
    $options.append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', tokarr[index]));
});
```

Comment: What is index here and value? Plz explain.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for such a simple answer:-)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `tokarr[count]` as string instead of a variable.
Change

```
$("#listbox").append("<option value=tokarr[count]>"+modarr[count]+"</option>");
```

to

```
val val = tokarr[count].replace(" ", "&amp;");
$("#listbox").append("<option value=" + val + ">"+modarr[count]+"</option>");
```

Comment: It works ,but if the tokarr[] has some element with space like,tokarr[2]="alc lanz" then it only adds "alc" to the value part of select element.

Comment: @edge You need to replace space with `&amp;`. I have updated my answer

Comment: Now it works for only one space. If more than one space, it does not show up.Also ,this time & is visible in place of space. Anyways thank you for suggesting me. As Rembo suggested,it works.